# Reconectar a la database después de recarar la página en NodeJs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy intentando hacer la paginación correctamente en `NodeJs`, pero a la hora de mandar los valores de un formulario a la `database` correspondiente y volver a la misma página del formulario, no se vuelve a conectar automáticamente a la `database`. Por lo que, si intento volver a hacer una `query` salta un error:

Aquí recojo la dependencia de `mysql` y creo la conexión a la `database` mediante la variable `connection` dentro del archivo `server,js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'base_de_pruebas'
});
```

Luego relleno el siguiente formulario en el `index.html`:

```
<!-- FORMULARIO DE INSERCIÓN DE VALORES -->
<form method="post" action="insertDb">
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bd_nom">
    <label>Apellidos:</label>
    <input type="text" name="bd_ape">
    <input type="text" name="bd_s_a">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Y luego me conecto a la `database`, hago la `query`, inserto los datos del formulario y cierro la conexión porque sino se queda abierta y no carga la página:

```
//  POST FORM
app.post('/insertDb', (req, res) => {
    let formNomBD=req.body.bd_nom;
    let formApeBD=req.body.bd_ape;
    let formSApBD=req.body.bd_s_a;

    console.log(formNomBD);
    console.log(formApeBD);
    console.log(formSApBD);

    //Imprimimos en consola si hay un error que impida la conexión o por el contrario, nos dirá si la conexión es correcta
connection.connect(function(error){
   if(error){
      console.log('No se ha podido conectar');
   }
   else{
    console.log('Conectado a: ' + connection.config.database);
        var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO Pruebas(nombre, apellido, s_apellido) VALUES(?, ?, ?)', [formNomBD, formApeBD, formSApBD], function(error, result){
   if(error){
      console.log(error);
   }else{
      console.log(result);
   }
 }
);
   connection.end();
   }
});
//  res.send('Insertada la persona ' + formNomBD + ' ' + formApeBD + ' ' + formSApBD + '.');
    res.sendfile('./response.html');
});
```

Bien, esto lo hace UNA vez. Al mandar los datos del formulario me devuelve el archivo `response.html`, que consiste en un botón de vuelta al `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Response</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="/">
<input type="submit" value="Volver">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile("./index.html");
});
```

Y cuando regreso al index, a través del botón de retorno, no se vuelve a conectar a la `database`, y por tanto, no es capaz de volver a mandar los datos del formulario.
¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

Pd: También he probado haciendo que, al mandar los datos del formulario, en vez de redireccionar a `response.html` redireccione a `index.html`, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Te pasa esto, porque donde tienes puesto que inicialize la conexión lo hará solo cuando arrancas el servidor, luego ya no va a volver a abrirla de nuevo, ya que ese código no se ejecuta de nuevo.

Te recomiendo usar Connection pools para gestionar las conexiones:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections

Simplemente abres la conexión como lo estas haciendo, pero con `createPool`:

```
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 10,
  host            : 'example.org',
  user            : 'bob',
  password        : 'secret',
  database        : 'my_db'
});

pool.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);
});
```

De esta manera se encarga de gestionar las conexiones, y no te tienes que preocupar de cerrarlas, como mucho quizá deberías de cerrarla si puedes controlar cuando se para el servidor.

Comment: Me ha servido a las mil perfecciones! Muchísimas gracias, se ha resuelto el problema al 100%

Comment: Vale, ahora me genera otra duda que no encuentro y no quería molestar innecesariamente. Antes tenía el comando connection.config.database para poder obtener el nombre de la base de datos como valor e imprimirlo en consola. Con el pool eso lo he perdido, hay algún comando equivalente?

Comment: Creo que puedes llegar a lo mismo con pool.config.connectionConfig.database

Comment: Justo! Muchas gracias